# vector accessing non zero elements but output as zero

Tags: c++11, vector, std-pair

I' did this program what suppose save pairs of string ,int on one vector and print  the strings of the maximum number on vector 
but when i try to find this strings don't appears nothing so I try print all values of int's on vector and although was finding the maximum of 10 all values in the vector was printing as 0. Someone can explain was it occurred and how I can access the values , please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<string,int>> vsi;

bool paircmp(const pair<string,int>& firste,const pair<string,int>&    seconde );

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 vsi v(10);

 string s;
 int n,t;

 cin>>t;

 for (size_t i = 0;i < t;i++) {
  for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   cin>>s>>n;
   v.push_back(make_pair(s,n));
  }
  sort(v.begin(),v.end(),paircmp);
  int ma=v[v.size()-1].second;
  cout<<ma<<endl;
  for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
   cout << v.at(j).second  <<endl;
   if(v[j].second == ma)

   cout<<v[j].first<<endl;

  }

 }





return 0;
}

bool paircmp(const pair<string,int>& firste,const pair<string,int>& seconde ){
 return firste.second < seconde.second;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
vsi v(10);
```

creates you a `std::vector` filled with 10 default-constructed `std::pair<std::string, int>`s.  That is, an empty string and zero.

You then `push_back` other values to your vector but they happen to be sorted after those ten initial elements, probably because they all have positive `int`s in them.

Therefore, printing the `first` member of the first ten elements prints ten empty strings.

This is all I can guess from what you have provided.  I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with this code.

Try something like

```
for (const auto& item : v)
  {
    std::cout << "{ first: '" << item.first << "', "
              << "second: " << item.second << " }\n";
  }
```

to print all elements of the vector `v`.